# How can dynamodb secondary indexes be autoscaled with Cloudformation templates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've seen the examples for adding autoscaling to tables with cloudformation, but other than the "Apply same settings to global secondary indexes" checkbox in the dynamodb console, I don't see a way to define this with cloudformation templates.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to define the secondary index as an autoscaling target.

You need just to specify the index as the `resourceId` using `/index/**YOUR_INDEX_NAME**` as a suffix and using `dynamodb:index:WriteCapacityUnits` and `dynamodb:index:ReadCapacityUnits` as `ScalableDimension`.

E.g.

```
  SecIndexWriteCapacity:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
    Properties:
      MaxCapacity: 1000
      MinCapacity: 15
      ResourceId: !Sub "table/${MY_MAIN_TABLE}/index/${MY_SECONDARY_INDEX_NAME}"
      RoleARN: !GetAtt ScalingRole.Arn
      ScalableDimension: dynamodb:index:WriteCapacityUnits
      ServiceNamespace: dynamodb
  SecIndexReadCapacity:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
    Properties:
      MaxCapacity: 1000
      MinCapacity: 15
      ResourceId: !Sub "table/${MY_MAIN_TABLE}/index/MY_SECONDARY_INDEX_NAME"
      RoleARN: !GetAtt ScalingRole.Arn
      ScalableDimension: dynamodb:index:ReadCapacityUnits
      ServiceNamespace: dynamodb
  SecIndexWriteScalingPolicy:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: SecIndexWriteScalingPolicy
      PolicyType: TargetTrackingScaling
      ScalingTargetId: !Ref SecIndexWriteCapacity
      TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration:
        TargetValue: 50.0
        ScaleInCooldown: 30
        ScaleOutCooldown: 1
        PredefinedMetricSpecification:
          PredefinedMetricType: DynamoDBWriteCapacityUtilization
  SecIndexReadScalingPolicy:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: SecIndexReadScalingPolicy
      PolicyType: TargetTrackingScaling
      ScalingTargetId: !Ref SecIndexReadCapacity
      TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration:
        TargetValue: 50.0
        ScaleInCooldown: 30
        ScaleOutCooldown: 0
        PredefinedMetricSpecification:
          PredefinedMetricType: DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization
```

See also https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-use-aws-cloudformation-to-configure-auto-scaling-for-amazon-dynamodb-tables-and-indexes/

Comment: For the resourceId, should that be the actual DynamoDB name for the table and index? Or the CloudFormation Ref?

Comment: Found out it is the actual DynamoDB name for both the table and the index in the resourceId

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible.

Follow the official AWS example for the [DynamoDB/CloudFormation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html), but for each GSI you would need to create a separate ScalableTarget and a Scalable Policy. In the ScalableTarget properties use `table/my-table/index/my-table-index` notation for the ResourceId.